# How can I create a git hook that forces me to write javadoc comments?

Tags: java, git, documentation, javadoc, githooks

Is there a way for me to somehow parse my java code files and look for java doc comments? I want to make sure I've written javadocs for the class and each method of the class (or everything really). Is this possible?

Comment: Just doing what I'm supposed to do ;)

Comment: You would surprised how often one has to come back and remind people to collect their +2 points ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A serious non-answer: do **not** do this. Opinionated explanations will follow; but all of my input is rooted in a lot of experience around such topics.

The point is: sooner or later (rather sooner!) you will run into situations where you really really want to get your changes into git. Knowing that you need javadoc to make that possible, you will start putting down dummy content, like:

```
/** just to make the commit hook happy; @TODO: replace with real content */
```

And I guarantee you: sooner or later you will find that you got plenty of such @TODOS rotting in your code base for days, weeks, months. Because in the end, getting that new feature out to the customer that pays your salary is more important than fixing those 15 @TODOs you got somewhere. Did I say 15? Ah, that was last week. Now we have 25... ([LeBlanc's law](http://on-agile.blogspot.de/2007/04/why-you-wont-fix-it-later.html) *later equals never* kicks in! Guaranteed)

In other words: if you *would like* to have javadoc in all places, but your discipline is not "good enough" **today** to achieve that without such kind of enforcing; then that will lead to low-quality javadoc.

Beyond that: after focusing on "clean code" practices for several years I think today: having javadoc alone is **not** the answer. Although I am working in a large enterprise with teams spread around the globe.

To the contrary. When people are trained to write "readable" code, very often they actually don't need any (or just tiny bits of) javadoc to get there. Because then their designs and naming skills are on a level that code becomes easy to read without much javadoc.

And if people are not trained regarding this skill, they tend to create useless javadoc. I can't tell you how often I tell people to disable that eclipse template that creates an absolute useless @author tag when generating a new class. And guess what: still there are countless occurrences of eclipse-generated javadocs ... that were **never** touched by any developer after being generated.

Long story short: it needs a lot of discipline and skill to create **useful** javadoc. If you already lack discipline, then enforcing a "some javadoc must be there" rule will **not** increase the quality of your code!

Finally: I am not saying that one shouldn't look into such things completely. But I would rather suggest to

1. define common guidelines how javadoc should be written; what information is mandatory; and what kind of elements need javadoc
2. based on that, find ways to automatically check that
3. to then collect such information on a regular base (for example during nightly builds) and keep an eye on such statistics